# How to draw columns with same width in a custom control

Tags: c#, user-controls, system.drawing

I am making a custom grid control, and I need to draw columns with the same width. But the last column is about 1px narrow as shown in the image.

I think the code is fine, but doesn't work as expected.

Can you give me a hand?

**Solved**

The issue was control internal margins. When you set BorderStyle property to any value that means see any border the control is some pixels narrower.

[image: example-form]

Here is the code:

```
public partial class CustomGrid : Panel
{

    // number of columns to draw
    private int hrows;

    private bool drawgrid;

    // cell width
    private float cellwidth;

    private int rectwidth;
    private int rectheight;


    public void EnableGrid()
    {

        // ClientRect does not match with Control Size, so I used Control.Width
        this.rectwidth = this.Width;
        this.rectheight = this.Height;      

        // compute cell dimension
        this.cellwidth = (float)this.rectwidth / this.hrows;

        this.drawgrid = true;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.drawgrid)
        {

            float current = this.cellwidth;

            // draw columns
            while (current < this.rectwidth)
            {

                e.Graphics.DrawLine
                (
                    Pens.Black,
                    current,         //x1
                    0f,              //y1
                    current,         //x2
                    this.rectheight  //y2

                );

                current += this.cellwidth;
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: This is basic math, you can only ever get exactly equal sized columns if the ClientSize.Width of your control is exactly divisible by the number of columns. This will only ever happen by accident. You'll have to accommodate the width that was selected when the user dropped your control onto the form by either intentionally drawing your grid smaller, which gives you perfectly equal width columns. Or by distributing the available space across the columns, which will end up making some columns smaller by a pixel.